# Convert a ResultSet value into XML?

Tags: java

Is it possible to convert the value of a ResultSet (result of a query execution) into XML??!  If so which API would deal with this?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at these examples:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/WebRowSet.html

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/ConvertaResultSettoXML.htm